# How to create a process with vector in SimGrid?

Tags: c++, vector, simgrid

I want to create a process with data in SimGrid, so I do this:

```
int worker(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    vector<string> vector1;
    vector1.push_back("word");
    MSG_process_create("x", executor, &vector1, MSG_host_self());
    return 0;
}
```

But in `executor` I have a segmentation error:

```
int executor(int argc, char* argv[]){
    MSG_process_sleep(10);
    vector<string> *data = (vector<string>*) MSG_process_get_data(MSG_process_self());
    XBT_INFO("%s", data->front().c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

I know that it happened because `vector1` goes out of scope when `worker` function ends and `vector1` dissappered, so "there is no vector1 data" in executor.

How to do it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to use a pointer here :)

```
int worker(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    vector<string>* vector1 = new vector<string>();
    vector1->push_back("word");
    MSG_process_create("x", executor, vector1, MSG_host_self());
    return 0;
}

int executor(int argc, char* argv[]){
    MSG_process_sleep(10);
    vector<string> *data = (vector<string>*) MSG_process_get_data(MSG_process_self());
    XBT_INFO("%s", data->front().c_str());
    delete data;
    return 0;
}
```